# Expected Exception but nothing was raised using Rspec. Trying to raise_error when variable is empty

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I am trying to pass this last test, trying raise an exception I can't make it work. Is there something I'm not seeing? I've been looking at it for hours and looking for an answer, thank you in advance to anyone who might respond to this.

Error message :

Failure/Error: expect{birthday_list.show_birthdays}.to raise_error{'No birthdays avalible!'}
expected Exception but nothing was raised

Tests:

```
describe BirthdayList do
birthdays = @birthdays
birthday_list = BirthdayList.new


describe '#add' do
  it 'adds a birthday to the list' do
    expect(birthday_list.add('name','date')).to eq   ([{:dates=>"date", :names=>"name"}])
  end
end

describe '#show_birthdays' do
  it 'throws an error when there is no birthdays' do
  @birthdays = []
    expect{birthday_list.show_birthdays}.to raise_error{'No birthdays avalible!'}
  end

  it 'prints all birthdays' do


    expect(birthday_list.show_birthdays).to eq "name, date\n"
  end
end

end
```

And Code

```
class BirthdayList
  def initialize
    @birthdays = []
  end

  def add name,date
    birthday = {:names => name, :dates => date }
    @birthdays.push(birthday)
  end

 def show_birthdays
   raise 'No birthdays avalible!' unless @birthdays
   
   list_to_print = ''

   @birthdays.each do |b|
     print "#{b[:names]}, #{b[:dates]} \n"
   end

   @birthdays.each do |b|
     list_to_print += "#{b[:names]}, #{b[:dates]}\n"
   end

   list_to_print
end

 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your assertion does not look correct. The [raise_error](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) matcher needs the expected exception to be passed as a parameter instead of as a block.

Instead of:

```
  expect { my_code }.to raise_error { 'Oops!' }
```

you need to use:

```
  expect { my_code }.to raise_error('Oops!')
```

or any of the alternatives forms of the matcher.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It was actually this line 
'raise 'No birthdays avalible!' unless @ birthdays'  that wasn't working. It works now that I changed it to :
if @ birthdays == []
     raise'No birthdays avalible!'
   end

Comment: Also needed to change @birthdays = [] in the test to bday_list = BirthdayList.new and then use that in the test instead of birthday_list.